# error: invalid conversion from "const char*" to "char"

Tags: c++

This is on linux btw...

I'm getting this error from my code

```
m-server.cpp: In function âvoid* SocketHandler(void*)â:
m-server.cpp:187: error: invalid conversion from âcharâ to âconst void*â
m-server.cpp:187: error:   initializing argument 2 of âssize_t send(int, const void*, size_t, int)â
```

The part that's giving an error:

```
char welcomemsg;

cout << "Set the welcome message: ";
cin >> welcomemsg;

//send initial welcome data || msg & src
send(*csock, welcomemsg, sizeof(welcomemsg), 0); //this is line 187
```

---

**UPDATE**

I have changed my mind rather than cIN then msg, I'd just want to set it like the code below.

I'm getting this error from my code

```
m-server.cpp: In function âvoid* SocketHandler(void*)â:
m-server.cpp:181: error: invalid conversion from âconst char*â to âcharâ
m-server.cpp:230: error: jump to label âFINISHâ
m-server.cpp:177: error:   from here
m-server.cpp:181: error:   crosses initialization of âchar welcomemsgâ
m-server.cpp:230: error: jump to label âFINISHâ
m-server.cpp:161: error:   from here
m-server.cpp:181: error:   crosses initialization of âchar welcomemsgâ
m-server.cpp:230: error: jump to label âFINISHâ
m-server.cpp:149: error:   from here
m-server.cpp:181: error:   crosses initialization of âchar welcomemsgâ
```

The part that's giving an error:

```
char welcomemsg = "@hello_! bro?"; //can allow symbols? 

//send initial welcome data || msg & src
send(*csock, (void *)&welcomemsg, sizeof(welcomemsg), 0);
```

I'm new to c++ what is the problem here? how to fix? and whats the reason behind it?

---

**UPDATE**

The server didnt have any errors after i changed it to this.

```
char *welcomemsg = "hello";

//send initial welcome data || msg & src
send(*csock, welcomemsg, sizeof(welcomemsg), 0);
```

But now the client crashes when its receiving the welcome message. Why?
This is the code that I used with the server and the client was reading the welcome message fine.

```
send(*csock, "Hello_Word", 10, 0); //was a working code
```

---

**UPDATE**

I have checked and client crashes on recv()
What difference does this code have to all the suggestions? Why was this code working well with no crashing client?

```
send(*csock, "Temporarily Offline_Server will open sockets on Jan. 14, 2013", 61, 0); //was a working code
```

---

**UPDATE**

My recv() code:

```
response = "";
resp_leng= BUFFERSIZE;
while (resp_leng == BUFFERSIZE)
{
    resp_leng= recv(sock, (char*)&buffer, BUFFERSIZE, 0);
    if (resp_leng>0)
        response+= string(buffer).substr(0,resp_leng);
}
```

Comment: -1 for completely changing the question.

Comment: **welcomemsg[]**, and ***never completely rewrite a question from scratch.*** It utterly invalidates any comments or answers posted prior and generally makes for totally useless content for StackOverflow (not that this is a high priority for you, but it should be).

Comment: Hello, I'm really sorry about that and I've edited it back.

Comment: How can I get voted down too much? :/

Answer (score 2):

Despite what is stated in other answers, the explicit conversion to `[const] void *` type is completely unnecessary. However, taking the address of your `welcomemsg` object is indeed necessary

```
send(*csock, &welcomemsg, sizeof welcomemsg, 0);
```

The above will fix the compiler error.

However, I'd guess that the problem actually has different nature. Did you intend your "welcome msg" to consist of only one character? Your `welcomemsg` variable is declared as a single character. If you intended it to be longer that one character, then you should have declared it as an array

```
char welcomemsg[100]; // for example
```

In this case the `&` would become unnecessary

```
send(*csock, welcomemsg, sizeof welcomemsg, 0);
```

However, in that case (if you are sending a string), you have to decide what it is exactly that you want to send. You can send the whole array object, i.e. `sizeof welcomemsg` bytes as in the example above. Or you can send just the significant characters of the string, i.e. `strlen(welcomemsg)` bytes (or `strlen(welcomemsg) + 1` bytes) as in

```
send(*csock, welcomemsg, strlen(welcomemsg), 0);
```

If the message is represented as

```
const char *welcomemsg = "some message";
```

you would have to use the latter variant.

But when you send strings like that, with run-time length, the issue of receiving that string becomes more complicated. How will the receiving code know how much bytes to receive? Normally, one would send the length first and then follow it by the actual string data.

Comment: `sizeof` is unnecessary with `char`. And using fixed-length buffers is a very bad idea.

Comment: @larsmans: `sizeof` with `char` is a matter of style. Moreover, in this case it is not with `char` explicitly, but with `welcomemsg`. I.e. `sizeof` is actually more than appropriate in this case to make this code type-independent. The code should not rely on the fact that `welcomemsg` is `char`. On top of that, as I explained in my answer, it is quite possible it wasn't supposed to be `char` at all.

Comment: the code crucially depends on the fact that `welcomemsg` is a `char`; for all other types, `&welcomemsg` would be unreliable, if not an outright error.

Comment: @larsmans: Absolutely not. If the intent is to send the object `welcomemsg`, then the best code (and well-established idiom) is `&welcomemsg, sizeof welcomemsg` regardless of the actual type of `welcomemsg`. If the intent is to send the object *pointed by* `welcomemsg`, then the best code (and well-established idiom) is `welcomemsg, sizeof *welcomemsg`. The third option would be about sending a run-time sized object. The author is supposed to make the right choice among these three options and then follow one of the three idioms. Nothing "unreliable" here.

Comment: Writing explicit `sizeof(char)` in the code might be excessive, since it is indeed always `1` (still a matter of style). But writing `sizeof var` is always appropriate regardless of the type of `var` (even if it happens to be `char`). This is one of the foundation principles of writing type-independent code. There's no room for discussion here.

Comment: I'm working on linux btw. Thanks. I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: I tried your updated answer, do you have any suggestions for me? I'm just trying to do something like this because I'll then try to make it read from a file that contains the welcome message. Any idea? Anyways, the updated code still makes the client crash on recv.

Comment: @user1858564: There's no way to tell why your `recv` crashes without seeing the `recv` code. How many bytes does `recv` receive? How does it allocate the recipient buffer? How big is the buffer?

Comment: i edited my question with the recv code.

Answer (score 0):

`send` is expecting a void pointer as its second argument: `send(int, const void*, size_t, int)`

Change your code to:

```
send(*csock, (void *)&welcomemsg, sizeof(welcomemsg), 0);
```

The `&` notation gets the address of `welcomemsg`.
The `(void *)` part isn't necessary, but it casts the address from a pointer to a char to a void pointer.

---

**Updated question:** if you want to use:

```
char welcomemsg = "hello";

//send initial welcome data || msg & src
send(*csock, (void *)&welcomemsg, sizeof(char) * 6, 0);
```

Then you need to change it to:

```
char *welcomemsg = "hello";

//send initial welcome data || msg & src
send(*csock, welcomemsg, strlen(welcomemsg), 0);
```

Since `welcomemsg` is now a pointer to the start of the character array "hello", there is already an address.

Comment: I have changed my mind about the code, can you check the updated question?

Comment: Pls do not do this sort of thing. It renders all the answers useless.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. I'm also new here.

Comment: @user1858564: see updated answer, you need to specify the length of the message: `sizeof(char) * 6` - it's 6 because "hello" is terminated with `'\0'`

Comment: is there no way to get the length other than specifying it? I want to set the welcome message from a txt file. ill try to ifstream it and get the line and insert it into variable welcomemsg, how do i get the length if thats the case?

Comment: i've tried the latest edit. and client still crashes.

Comment: @user1858564 sorry, I'm tired; see updated answer: you can use `strlen(welcomemsg)` to find the length of the char array pointed at by `welcomemsg`

Comment: Thanks for that info. But it still crashes the client. anyways you should get some rest. Thank for the help.

Answer (score 0):

that should be `send(*csock, (void *)&welcomemsg, sizeof(welcomemsg), 0);`

Answer (score 0):

Let me address some of the bugs I see.

```
char *welcomemsg = "hello";
send(*csock, welcomemsg, sizeof(welcomemsg), 0);
```

`sizeof(welcomemsg)` will return the size of a pointer. I believe you actually want to send the string, not a pointer to it (which would be meaningless on the receiver side). You may want to set it to `strlen(welcomemsg)+1`. Note, +1 is needed to send the end-of-string character!

```
send(*csock, "Hello_Word", 10, 0); //was a working code
```

If it worked, you were lucky. You want to send `{'H','e','l','l','o','_','W','o','r','d','\0'}` which consists of 11, not 10 bytes.
If the receiver had already 0 after it, it worked correctly, but anything else most likely will lead to a crash on the receiver end.

To ease the pain of counting for different strings (literals or not) you can implement a simple wrapper function:

```
void sendString(int socket_descriptor, const char* str) {
    send(socket_descriptor, str, strlen(str)+1, 0);
}
```

This should work as long as `str` is a proper null-terminated C-string.

---

I strongly suggest you play with C-strings a little bit, learn how they function, how to pass them between functions, etc, before trying to send them over the network.